# What are this files do?

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, files

i'm new to ubuntu while i searched for files i found

```
BitStormLite 
ec_storm_threshold 
rrefpropstormin.html 
StormbaanCoureur
weather-storm.svg
```

what are this files do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- weather-storm.svg is in ubuntu by default (it is a vector image)
- I am guessing bitstormlite is [this](https://launchpad.net/bitstormlite) (a torrent client)
- ec_storm_threshold I have no idea what it is, so I would leave it alone.
- StormbaanCoureur is a linux game
- rrefpropstormin.html is just a html file, so probably useless

These are probably unrelated to the program you removed.

Answer (score 0):

The .html seems to be an HTML code, and the .svg is probably a vectorial image. But the files without an extension are hard to know just by looking at their names. Why don't you open a Terminal window, cd to the directory where these files are in (run the command 'cd /path/to/directory') and then run 'file filename'? The 'file' command will try to tell you something about the specified file.

Comment: is there any problem to delete them ? i mean is that files for system files or not  ? because i have program  want ot remove it called storm and i delete all files related to it